# PowerQuery - transform 1:N Relation to one single line per record

Tags: powerquery

I need to transform this table

| _project_value | statusdatum | tasktext |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b016d0ce-03af-eb11-8236-000d3a2c9d3d | 07.05.2021 | Status A |
| e2ac5411-9035-eb11-a813-000d3a2bc66a | 08.04.2021 | Status A |
| e2ac5411-9035-eb11-a813-000d3a2bc66a | 30.04.2021 | Status B |
| e2ac5411-9035-eb11-a813-000d3a2bc66a | 17.05.2021 | Status C |
| e2ac5411-9035-eb11-a813-000d3a2bc66a | 01.12.2020 | Status D |

into

| _project_value | Status A | Status B | Status C | Status D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| b016d0ce-03af-eb11-8236-000d3a2c9d3d | 07.05.2021 |  |  |  |
| e2ac5411-9035-eb11-a813-000d3a2bc66a | 08.04.2021 | 30.04.2021 | 17.05.2021 | 01.12.2020 |

via PowerQuery, I searched a lot but no answer matched my problem. Is this even possible?

Rafael

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the tasktext column to highlight it

Transform ... pivot column...

Values Column: statusdatum

Advanced Options...Aggregate Value Function .. Don't Aggregate..

[image]